# Magento 1.9: Form Key is generating on each refresh

Tags: magento-1.9

**some items in cart having different form_key & others having different keys**. Because of that items having old key can not delete from cart & **form_key is generating on every refresh**.

I found that if we add one specific product type 'giftcards' then products after giftcards having new key & products before the 'giftcards' type having incorrect(old) key.

Still finding the cause for regeneration the form_key because of new product type. Anyone have idea on that?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this??

Comment: Couldn't found exact issue. At last I end up by adding some `jquery` code to update the valid form_key to the product delete URL.